# Issue getting height of element when using jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m having an issue with my script that loads content to a page via jQuery .load(). The content loads properly, my animation of said content works (done with class "hidden"), but I’m setting the height of the wrapping container before loading, and then animating the height of said container to keep the page from jumping between the different content heights.

Essentially what’s happening, is the height is getting set to 0 for some reason, rather than the actual height of the element. Strangely, this seems to work on the initial click, but then on any others it breaks and sets the height to 0.

See the code below (I would create a jsFiddle but, .load() doesn't work with that):

**HTML**

```
<main id="content" class="content">
    <div id="content-inner" class="content-inner">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    transition: .25s height;
}

.content-inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

    transition: .25s opacity, .25s top;
}

.hidden .content-inner {
    top: -30px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;

    transition: .25s opacity, .25s top, 0s visibility .25s;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
var $mainContentOuter = $('#content'),
    linkContent = '#content-inner',
    $mainContentInner = $(linkContent);


function loadMainContent(link) {

    // Assign height as current height to prevent jumping
    $mainContentOuter.height( $mainContentInner.outerHeight() );

    // Hide content
    $mainContentOuter.addClass('hidden').delay(250).queue(function() { 

        // Load content
        $mainContentOuter.load(link + ' ' + linkContent, function() {

            // Animate the height difference when loaded
            $mainContentOuter.height($mainContentInner.outerHeight());

        });

        // Dequeue for delay
        $(this).dequeue();

    }).delay(250).queue(function() {

        // Reveal content and reset height
        $mainContentOuter.removeClass('hidden').css('height','');

        // Dequeue for delay
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
}

// Override behavior of navigational links
$('.nav-main > li > a').click(function(e){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    //Pass link
    loadMainContent(link);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @thanasis I realized what was going on here.

The variable `$mainContentInner` was storing a reference to the original object in the DOM. Once the page content was loaded, this object was removed and replaced with another one, albeit similar.

Even though they have the same ID, they're different objects. To get around this, I redefined the variable, so as to target the new object. See below:

```
    // Load content
    $mainContentOuter.load(link + ' ' + linkContent, function() {

        // Redefine $mainContentInner to the new object
        $mainContentInner = $(linkContent);

        // Animate the height difference when loaded
        $mainContentOuter.height($mainContentInner.outerHeight());

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you load the inner-content inside the outer content, so there is no inner-content after the load takes place. Try using:

```
$mainContentOuter.load(link + ' ' + '#content', function() {

    // Animate the height difference when loaded
    $mainContentOuter.height($mainContentInner.outerHeight());

});
```

Imagine it like you have 2 rectangles A and B, where B is inside A. If you load everything that B has and give it to A then there will be no B, but only A because B didn't have B in it, so A won't have B in it either. I recently encoutered a similar problem and it took me hours to understand and solve it. Please let me know if this solved your problem!

Comment: I'm actually replacing #content-inner with an equivalent container from the page being loaded. So, it does still exist?

Comment: Man, I feel really stupid now. An element exists with the same properties, but it's not technically the same element. The old one was targeted with that variable, but since it's been technically deleted, it's height is 0, or more likely undefined. I seemingly fixed the problem by resetting the variable after the content loads: `$mainContentInner = $(linkContent);`

Comment: Don't feel stupid. These things happen all the time. I have spent many hours trying to solve mistakes much easier than this one. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Also, if I reloaded the content into the outer container I wouldn't be able to control the height, and the height difference would snap, rather than animate. Plus, there's a chance that something goes wrong or is delayed, and anything below the container being replaced, snaps up to the top of the screen for a second.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although your answer didn't *directly* solve, it led to the solution! Sometimes you just gotta talk it out!